# NGINX access-rights using string-interpolated file location

Tags: nginx, ssl

I found something curious about the nginx configuration.
Whenever I put a string-literal as certificate/key-file location everything works fine. But since I need a bit more dynamic logic I tried `maps`. But apparently when you include a variable into the file-string, nginx doesn't use its root privileges meaning it cannot open the certificate?

example (this works perfectly):

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    server_name _;
    
    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    
    # rest of the configuration stuff
}
```

example (this doesn't somehow):

```
map $host $cert_name {
    mydomain.com        mydomain.com;
    www.mydomain.com    mydomain.com;
    default             mydomain.com;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    server_name _;
    
    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/$cert_name/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/$cert_name/privkey.pem;
    
    # rest of the configuration stuff
}
```

This wil yield in the following error message:

```
cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib) while SSL handshaking, client: #client-ip#, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

additional info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
nginx: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)  built with OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020  TLS SNI support enabled
nginx started as root user?: yes
letsencrypt folder permissions: default
```

Would this be a security feature? or a bug?

In any case, is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For if anyone stumbles on this problem.
I found the answer in the [letsencrypt documentation](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#id31).

Basically the `/etc/letsencrypt/live` and `/etc/letsencrypt/archive` directories are created with permission `0700` for legacy reasons. When using the latest version of cerbot it is safe to set the permissions to `0755`. The command they provided is:

`chmod 0755 /etc/letsencrypt/{live,archive}`

This allows non-root users to access all public certificates, while the private-keys are still only accessible by the `root` user/super-users. As it turns out, this is exactually what nginx does which means everything should work after changing the permissions.